# How to add generic Throwable on a method signature

Tags: kotlin, generics

How can I create a Map (it that's the best way) of having something for instance :

400 to CustomExceptionFor400

500 to CustomExceptionFor500

The first param is an Int and it's a `HttpStatusCode`, and the value is something like this

```
sealed class OrganizationExceptions : Exception() {
    object OrganizationNotFound : OrganizationExceptions()
    object ListNotAvailable : OrganizationExceptions()
}
```

This is an example, but it won't be always `OrganizationExceptions` I'm creating a method generic, also I don't know if it's better to create a sealed class or create

```
class OrganizationNotFoundException : Throwable() //or Exception()
class ListNotAvailable : Throwable() //or Exception()
```

Any recomendations?
the method signature is :

```
fun apiCallWithStatusCode(codes : HashMap<Int, Throwable>, apiCall : suspend () -> Response<T>,):Result<Unit>{...}
```

So my method should return a `Result` so it means that if the `HttpStatusCode` is 400 I should return `return Result.failure(CustomExceptionFor400)` that is the one that should come in the `codes` from the method.

### PSEUDO EXAMPLE OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE

```
suspend fun <T : Throwable> apiCallWithStatusCode(
    codes: Map<Int, T>,
    apiCall: suspend () -> Response<T>,
): Result<Unit> {
    runCatching { apiCall() }
        .fold(
            onSuccess = { response ->
                if (response.isSuccessful) Result.success(Unit)
                return codes[response.code()]?.let {
                    Result.failure(it)
                } ?: Result.failure(GeneralError)
            },
            onFailure = {
                return when (it) {
                    //Return Result.failure(WhateverError) this is done already
                }
            }
        )
}
```

But I don't know if that's the way to do it.
My questions are :
What's better

```
sealed class OrganizationExceptions : Exception() {
    object OrganizationNotFound : OrganizationExceptions()
    object ListNotAvailable : OrganizationExceptions()
}
```

Or

```
class OrganizationNotFoundException : Throwable() //or Exception()
class ListNotAvailable : Throwable() //or Exception()
```

Then after knowing this, is to create this generic function because now there are two "OrganizationNotFoundException" and "ListNotAvailable" but perhaps other feature of my app have different Exceptions so that's why I want to have a generic one.

Comment: [You should not reuse instances of exceptions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090664/is-it-safe-to-store-an-instance-of-an-exception-and-reuse-it) anyway. So at best for this to work you would need to provide a `Map<Int, () -> Throwable>` to create new instances every time. That said, why do you need specific different exceptions for your generic method? Why not use the same exceptions that are themselves generic in their names? If you want more context, this is the point of the stacktrace. If you want more specific exceptions, this is the point of the exception causes.

Comment: @Joffrey I'm not reusing the instance of the exception I'd like to create a new one every-time. I'm going to update my question and do a pseudo example.

Comment: Using `object` is obviously wrong because there would be only one instance, and thus you would be reusing the same exception over and over. Even with your other option, if you pass a `Map<Int, Throwable>`, it will be wrong too because the exception will be created in a different place than where it's thrown, so the stacktrace will be messed up

Comment: Ok, true, object is incorrect, then is there any way I still have this apiCall with the wrapper of Result<T> and create a lambda when it's result so wherver I use this function I can do it in the correct place instead of being generic?

Comment: I mean, have the generic errors but then on each data-source have my own implementation of if it's 200 X if it's 202 Y, etc.. it would be a bit boilerplate but I don't know other way

Comment: Could elaborate on why you need this? Why not just throw the exceptions corresponding to different error codes, and catch them in higher-level methods if you need to handle them differently (especially if you need to return results like `null` for "not found" etc.). Basically my question is "what's the point?", how would you structure the calling code if you could make this function the way you want?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the clean architecture so the data does the retrofit call to the server, so if the response is ok I send Result.success(Unit) then if it's ok but the status code is 400 for instance I need to do something extra on the app so I've created a domain exceptions to return them instead of throwing exception. Then it goes to the domain layer the "domain exception" then to the presentation I can get what happened because I don't want the presentation know the code status. if you know other way could you put a sample of code of it?

Comment: I'm doing it like this because I'm using the Result<T> class and I want to avoid the try catch if I already have the success and failure. And I'm doing a generic one because it's gonna be always the same at least for the success (unless it's not Unit) and the failure is because retrofit throws an exception and I'm catching them. but I'm not going to do always the if it's 404 it's ListNotFound perhaps on apiCallX I want the 401 because whatever so that's why I would like to pass the pair or whatever key (status code) value (domain exception)